# Delete action_settings on ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I'm having problems when i'm trying to delete the settings icon and add another new icon.

What I've tried is (noone worked out) :

1.-Delete the item in main.xml

2-Change the `OnPrepareOprionMenu`

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if Navigation drawer is opened, hide the action items
boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_home).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

3.-Change the `OnOptionsItemSelected`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //  title/icon
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_home:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

4.-My `menu_home.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="r"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

5.-Also I've tried this, on my fragment (where I want to show this home icon)

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home,menu );
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(false);

    }
```

5.- The main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"/>

      <item
        android:id="@+id/action_rate"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_rateapp"/>

</menu>
```

I know it's not that hard, but i don't get why it does not dissapear of my app.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `action_settings` menu item in `R.menu.menu_home`. It must be in `R.menu.main` which you are also inflating but you didn't post the XML for this menu.

Comment: The thing is that I've created another menu, but action_settings is on R.menu.main (i've edited my post)...

Comment: Why are you using two different menu files?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with inflating multiple menu files. But what's your actual problem? With this setup I expect that settings should be hidden and you should be left with a home icon and refresh and rate in the overflow menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... the thing that I did is change the `main.xml` and `menu_main.xml`

My `main.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="Home"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="r"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

And I saw I had a `menu_main.xml` then I deleted all and added :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="Home"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="r"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

And I had to modify some stuff on my `MainActivity.java`.

That worked to me...

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked before with that said to rebuild the menu on the support actionbar call

```
super.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

onCreateOptionsMenu is then called

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.mapmain, menu);

            boolean isSDCardReady = MyCheckStorage
                    .isExternalStorageWritable();

            // The snapshot or thumbnail create option is not available
            // unless the sdcard isready
            MenuItem menuItemSnapshot = menu.findItem(R.id.action_snapshot);
            if (isSDCardReady) {
                menuItemSnapshot.setEnabled(true);
                menuItemSnapshot.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                menuItemSnapshot.setEnabled(false);
                menuItemSnapshot.setVisible(false);
            }
...

return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```